# How to test a swallowed exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

I spent some time looking for a way of resolving my issue but with no success! 
Here is my problem: I have got some code that does the following:

```
public void DoSomething(){
    try{
       DoStuffThatCanThrowException();
    }catch(Exception e){
       // Do nothing...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `try catch` block swallows all exceptions that can be thrown in the `DoStuffThatCanThrowException()`. 
I am trying hard to think of a way to write a unit test that basically ensures that no exception is thrown in the `DoStuffThatCanThrowException()`. The difficulty here is that I can neither change the `try catch` block nor the `DoStuffThatCanThrowException()` method.

Any hints are highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
One important detail I forgot to mention, I can not call `DoStuffThatCanThrowException` directly as it is `internal` and so is not visible from the outside world.

Comment: Looks like a big code smell. Any *good* reason you can't change the method? Seems kinda silly logic to have a try/catch around something you are trying to *prove* cannot hit an exception.

Comment: Can you control anything about the situation (permissions, existence of files, configuration, anything) to ensure that the exception does get thrown?

Comment: it seems like you're not doing unit testing, since you're testing a unit of code and depending on the result of another unit of code to validate your test. I'd test DoStuffThatCanThrowException() separately and then mock the call to the method using dependency injection

Comment: Another option is to use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` for the assembly

Comment: Can you access the assembly the `DoStuffThatCanThrowException` is defined in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for mess with the answer, maybe reflection will help you to dig in?

```
ClassContainingInternalMethod cl = new ClassContainingInternalMethod ();

//any private or internal method you want here.
MethodInfo dynMethod = 
cl.GetType().GetMethod("DoSomeStuff", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

dynMethod.Invoke(cl, new object[] {});
```

Comment: He said "The difficulty here is that I can neither change the try catch block nor the DoStuffThatCanThrowException() method."

Comment: @cookieMonster this is not possible, I can't change that bit of code :(

Comment: +1 This is the closest answer that seem to have a chance to work, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just call DoStuffThatCanThrowException from a unit test itself, therefore not being surrounded by try...catch at all?

**Edit**: Just seen that your method is internal. I'd suggest for the purposes of your test you make a public method which wraps it. That way you can test things temporarily. Once you are sure that the method cannot fail you have no further need for the try...catch in the first place.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that is unfortunately not possible. Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Can you call `DoStuffThatCanThrowException()` directly? If not, make a subclass of the original class that contains that try catch block and call it from there without the catch block.

```
class ClassUnderTest extends OriginalClass
{
    @Override
    public void functionToTest()
    {
             DoStuffThatCanThrowException()
    }

}
```

Also, testing for the absence of exceptions is difficult. You need to find all the potential exceptions that can be thrown and test around that. Even then, all you're saying is that "give these tests, no exceptions were thrown". This is less powerful than saying "Exceptions will never be thrown", but is usually good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Add a positive assert immediately after the call to `DoStuffThatCanThrowException()`, within the try block. If an exception occurs then the assert won't be executed. Or, add a negative assert inside the `catch` block. Not sure if this answers your question; it's not very clear.